# how to use hashmap for string and dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, hashmap

I want to implement a use case through hashmap in python. I will be having a json object of type dict.

```
x={
  "name": "Jim",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "phonenumber": "123456"
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "toyota", "mpg": 23.5},
    {"model": "kia", "mpg": 21.1}
  ]
}
```

```
if (x["married"] == True):
h.put(x[phonenumber]) // i want to make phonenumber as key and the entire dict x as value. by using something like Map<String, dict> h = new HashMap<>();
```

when i do h.get(phonenumber), i want the entire dict x as an output.
How can i implement this usecase in python.

Comment: Why not just use the phone number value as a key in another dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dict` is python's version of a hash map. To do what you want, try the following:

```
m = {}
if x["married"]:
    m[x["phonenumber"]] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, the `dict()` is Python's implementation of hastmaps / hash tables.  I've assumed that you are going to have many records, all of which will be stored in a `dict()`, and that you are adding records according to your example.  I have not error-checked for the existence of a phone number in the record; since you're using the phone number as the key then you should already have ensured that there is an actual phone number in the information which you are adding.

```
#just one record
x={
    "name": "Jim",
    "age": 30,
    "married": True,
    "phonenumber": "123456",   #you left out a comma here
    "pets": None,
    "cars": [
        {"model": "toyota", "mpg": 23.5},
        {"model": "kia", "mpg": 21.1}
    ]
}

my_dict = dict()   #this would hold ALL of your records

def add_to_mydict(my_dict:dict, new_record:dict):
    if new_record["married"]:
        phone = new_record.pop("phonenumber")
        y = {phone: new_record}
        my_dict.update(y)

add_to_mydict(my_dict, x)
print(my_dict)
```

`my_dict` would be the master dictionary in which you will store your data.  SQLite makes a much better database than in-memory `dict`s.